# CSS - Remove underline of <a href="#">

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i have something like this:

```
<a href="#"><span id="shorttext"><h4>V posledných dnech se událo mnoho změn, které byli velice výrazné. Proto neváhajte a podívete se i vy na to, co se vlastne zmenilo a nebo nezměnilo kdo vi... </h4></span></a>
```

I just move out  before span to make full block as href not just text and text become underline.

I try to fix it with something like:

```
h4 {
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;         /*text v slidery, opacity */
    font-color:FFFFFF;
}

a h4 {
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;         /*text v slidery, opacity */
    font-color:FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited h4{
    text-decoration:none;          
}
a:active h4{
    text-decoration:none;          
}
a:link h4{
    text-decoration:none;          
}
```

But it didnt really help, and advise?

Thanks for reading my post :)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a heading inside a span. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: a{text-decoration:none;}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underline is on the anchor, not the heading.

Remove it from *the anchor*.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would make much more sense to clear this up and give the `a` a clear `class` which indicates it's semantical meaning inside the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="whatever-fits"></a>
```

Then add style:

```
a.whatever-fits {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Additional remarks:

Your nesting of <strike>`a`</strike>, `h4` and `span` are [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

`font-color:FFFFFF;` has 2 mistakes:

1. there is no attribute called `font-color`, to style the color of text, you simply use `color`
2. hex colors need a leading `#`, e.g. `#FFFFFF`

Comment: Sadly the top answers on the question you are using as a reference for your nesting comment do not take into account the changes in HTML 5 (where anything non-interactive may appear inside an anchor).

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your comment; unfortunately I didn't research in detail. The HTML is still invalid as there is no heading allowed inside a span (copied above code into w3 validator).

Answer (score 1):

```
    h4 {
        padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;         /*text v slidery, opacity */
        color:#fff; }

    a h4 {
        padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;         /*text v slidery, opacity */
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration: none; }

    a:visited h4{
        text-decoration:none;           } 
a:active h4{
        text-decoration:none;           }
 a:link h4{
        text-decoration:none;           }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```